# Accessibility issue with pure CSS accordion

Tags: html, css, wai-aria

I have an accordion that I'm struggling to make keyboard accessible. I'm using an input element to track when user clicks on accordion and display the hidden content, which is what's causing the issue since the input it's set to display: none.

Is there a way around to making it accessible? I'm still learning about web accessibility. Would appreciate any tips!

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 12px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.accordion input[name="panel"] {
  display: none;
}

.accordion label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(65, 64, 66, 0.8);
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: FSHumanaRegular;
  margin-top: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.14, 0.095, 0.87);
}

.accordion label:after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fdb600;
}

.accordion label:hover {
  color: #fdb600;
}

.accordion input:checked + label {
  color: #fdb600;
}

.accordion input:checked + label:after {
  content: "-";
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

.accordion .accordion_content {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.425em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.14, 0.095, 0.87);
}

.accordion .accordion_content .accordion_body {
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 1.8em 0 1.5em;
}

input[name="panel"]:checked ~ .accordion_content {
  max-height: 1000em;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
       <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="panel" id="accordionContent">
        <label for="accordionContent">Historical Data</label>
        <div class="accordion_content">
         <div class="accordion_body">
                    <!-- CONTENT -->
                    <p>Hello, world!</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `make the accordion accessible`? To hide/show the content with keyboard interaction? Or something else?

Comment: @ChrisTapay Yes, currently you're not able to use the keyboard to access it.

Comment: just use the accordion pattern in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you shouldn't be using a checkbox to collapse/expand any element (bad practice). You can instead use a `<button>` that would trigger/control this functionality and on this button you should further add the proper ARIA values.

You can look into the following ARIA attributes to help you further enable accessibility on a collapsible element.

```
           aria-expanded="false" 
           aria-controls="collapsedElementId"
```

For example, Bootstrap's implementation of the collapse component uses such markup to enhance accessibility: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accessibility

Comment: I'd also add looking at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#disclosure, it's a fantastic resource for learning how to build accessible components.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm gathering too. Looks like I'll have to rework what I have to use a button instead. Thanks!